# Share common code between 2 iOS apps: Swift Package Manager? Cocoapods? Monorepo?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, swift-package-manager

I am about to start working on two new iOS apps, that will share a bunch of business logic, like the whole API layer plus the models. Instead of copying the shared code in both projects and trying to keep that in sync, I want to use some way to share the code.

My first though was that I'd use the Swift Package Manager. It's really easy to create a new package in Xcode, but I don't really know how to use the local version of the shared package in both apps while I am working on it, while also making it work for other devs (or CI!) checking out the apps. Can't really commit the apps having a local path dependency, because that would only work for me, right?

So, can I use a local version of that core package while working on the 2 apps and that core package, but still have it all pushed to GitHub and that it compiles on CI and for other devs too? Or would it only work on my machine since it would reference a local path?

Would using Cocoapods with a private pod make things easier or would I run into the exact same problem of working on a local path dependency on my computer, but wanting to have it work for other devs too?

Or should I just go with a monorepo containing both apps and the shared code, and just have everything use relative paths? Would a SPM package inside of the monorepo be helpful in this situation, or just use relative paths in both apps?

Comment: I am not sure but it sounds like you can solve your issue with basic versioning for the package. You can push all your commits to the github, but only use stable version for production and CI. Only thing you need to do is to change the version you are using in the main project and it should be fine. Not fully sure for PackageManager but I used Carthage with even specific commit. I think PackageManager should have something similar as well.

Comment: Private cocoapods work just fine in this scenario, especially when you develop them and your apps in parallel using "Development Pods"

Comment: @GüngörBasa can you explain how the versioning would help? What I don't want is that every time I add/change code to the core package, I have to immediately commit it just to test it.

Comment: @Gereon yea, I think a local dev pod would indeed be very easy, but how do you combine working on the local version, and yet still commit everything and having it work for other devs and/or CI?

Comment: Nothing keeps you from committing and releasing the dev pod using private repos and specs, and your CI should only access released versions. How you grant access to your pod and your private spec repo varies from CI to CI, but usually either deploy keys or github PATs work - at least that's how I do this on github with github actions.

Coworkers can switch between a local dev pod and a release very easily by editing their Podfile.

Comment: Right, so edit your podfile to point to the local version... and remember to not commit that. Not ideal but doable.

Comment: Remember that the Podfile is ruby code, you can make that switch dependent on environment variables or dot files (that's what I do, my projects have a `.pod_source` file that I can override using `$POD_SOURCE` and that feeds a `case` statement for the `pod` command I want.

Comment: If you turn that into an answer (with an example maybe), I can accept that 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend creating a (private) cocoapod for your business logic. Both your apps can refer to that cocoapod either via the release, somewhere in the repo or as a development pod, as needed.

In order to avoid editing `Podfile` all the time, you can control your pod's source via external files and/or environment variables. Here's what I do in a couple of my projects:

```rb
def library_pod
  src = ENV["POD_SOURCE"]
  if src == nil && File.file?(".pod_source")
    src = File.foreach(".pod_source").first.chomp
  end
  src = (src || "").split(":")
  case src[0]
  when "dev"
    # local dev pod, editable
    pod 'MyLibrary', :path => '../mylibrary', :inhibit_warnings => false
  when "head"
    pod 'MyLibrary', :git => 'https://github.com/mycompany/MyLibrary'
  when "branch"
    pod 'MyLibrary', :git => 'https://github.com/mycompany/MyLibrary', :branch=> src[1]
  else
    # default: use the release version 
    pod 'MyLibrary'
  end
end

target 'MyApp' do
  pod 'Pod1'
  pod 'Pod2'
  library_pod
end
```

where usually I have `POD_SOURCE=dev` in the environment on my dev machine. `.pod_source` contains `release` on master, and whatever branch name is appropriate in feature branches, so that my CI can to the right thing.

Comment: While this is a traditional approach, it is actually the slowest approach and usually ill-advised INTERNALLY within a company/organization.

Package boundaries are EXPENSIVE, especially when you have to both version them separately as well as house them separately (ie: separate code repo).

Have a look here for a monorepo approach, and by all means take the time to set [this](https://medium.com/reachnow-tech/swift-package-manager-in-a-monorepo-430665228594) up. Your development flow will be much better off as a result of it.